# How to create a multiple wildcard url pattern in web.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, web.xml

*How would one route the following path in Jetty ?*

```
/users/user_id/transactions/transaction_id
```

I tried it this way:

```
/users/*/transactions/*
```

But I'm getting an error stating below :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet Spec 12.2 violation: glob '*' can only exist at end of prefix based matches: bad spec `"/users/*/transactions"`

What is the solution to this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `web.xml`, if you give an URL pattern like this down below :

```xml
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

So, the URL pattern `/users/*` denotes that all those requests will be accepted that starts with `/users/` and ends with anything. For example : `/users/get/all`

But you can't give an URL pattern like `/users/*/anything/*/..` which is not allowed.

**A screenshot of 12.2 Specification of Mapping from [Oracle - Java™ Servlet Specification Book - Version 
 4.0](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf)** :

[image]

Comment: Too bad! I had no idea it would be impossible.

Comment: I have added the pdf. Please refer to it.

Comment: If you don't mind working with non-standard Jetty only features, there is a way to use URI Templates or Regex to map servlets (but not via the `WEB-INF/web.xml`).  You interested?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt it would be great if you can share an link with the description of jetty regex map.